# Retrieve svn repository folder content

Tags: perl, svn, repository, client, directory

*I'm writing a program (a Perl script - but technology is not critical) that looks into svn repository.*

It should retrieve content of the folder (including subfolders and files) and sort those files by last modification date.

**Do you know how this can be implemented?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to locate subversion-perl or the SVN::Client package (actually there were also SVN::FS, etc).

Without these module but the svn cli? Execute svn commands like "svn list", "svn log" and read the stdout back to the perl program to do this.

About "sort those files by last modification date."....

You may need to do "svn info" for each of the files to collect its "Last Change Date" after "svn list", definitely refer to the latest revision, and no idea if there's any faster method.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Thanks :)
Can you tell me from which repository can I install this package using Perl Package Manager?